# Comparing strings by using two different queues

Tags: c++, string, queue, deque

just started working with queues and need a push in the right direction.

"Write a program that reads two sentences and reads them into two separate queues. The program should then determine whether the sentences are identical by comparing characters between the two. When two non-identical characters are encountered, the program should display a message indicating that the sentences are not the same. If both queues contain the same set of characters, a message should be stated that they are identical."

I have tried a few things to no avail. I'm having trouble understanding what I'm supposed to do in order to access the characters from the string in such a way that I can compare the two.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    deque<string> str1, str2;

    string s;

    cout << "Enter string #1: ";
    cin >> s;

    str1.push_back(s);

    cout << "Enter string #2: ";
    cin >> s;

    str2.push_back(s);

    // both queues have their respective strings. what now?
}
```

Comment: `pop_front` is the dequeue operation for a queue. Does that point you in the right direction?

Comment: This question is typically unclear but I *think* it means you need to read the sentences one letter at a time into each queue. So you really need something like `std::queue<char> q;`

Comment: It seems kinda stupid to have queues with just 1 item. Are you sure you're not supposed to store individual chars in them? And then just pop chars until end or mismatch.

Comment: Yeah, your professor most likely wants you to compare character by character.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `std::queue` instead of `std::deque`.

The program can look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s1;

    std::cout << "Enter sentence #1: ";
    std::getline( std::cin, s1 );

    std::string s2;

    std::cout << "Enter sentence #2: ";
    std::getline( std::cin, s2 );

    std::queue<char> q1;
    for ( char c : s1 ) q1.push( c );

    std::queue<char> q2;
    for ( char c : s2 ) q2.push( c );

    while ( !q1.empty() && !q2.empty() && q1.front() == q2.front() )
    {
        q1.pop();
        q2.pop();
    }

    if ( q1.empty() && q2.empty() )
    {
        std::cout << "\nThe two sentences are identical" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\nThe two sentences differ" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```